# How do I get the type signature of the range function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Many functions in Haskell made up of special characters in Haskell are infix functions. These include `*`, `+`, `==`, `/`, etc. To get the type signatures of such functions you put the function in parentheses and execute `:t`, like so:

```
GHCi> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

I wanted to try and get the type signature of the range function, `[a..a]`, but it seems that this function is infix, but can only be used within a list `[]`. I tried all the following, but none worked:

```
GHCi> :t (..)
<interactive>:1:2: parse error on input `..'
GHCi> :t ([..])
<interactive>:1:3: parse error on input `..'
GHCi> :t [..]
<interactive>:1:2: parse error on input `..'
GHCi> :t ..
<interactive>:1:1: parse error on input `..'
```

Does anyone know how to get the type signature of the range function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `..` is not a function, it's actually syntax sugar. It gets translated to one of several functions: `enumFrom`, `enumFromThen`, `enumFromTo` or `enumFromThenTo`.

It can't be a normal function because it has four forms that work in different ways. That is, all four of these are valid:

```
[1..]     -- enumFrom 1
[1,2..]   -- enumFromThen 1 2
[1..10]   -- enumFromTo 1 10
[1,2..10] -- enumFromThenTo 1 2 10
```

These forms use the four functions I mentioned respectively.

If it was just a normal operator, `1..` would give you a partially applied function; instead, it produces a list. Moreover, for a normal function, the `[1,2..10]` notation would be parsed as `[1,(2..10)]` where in reality it all gets turned into a single function taking all three numbers as arguments.

These functions are all part of the `Enum` class, so the `..` notation works for any type that is part of it. For example, you could write `[False ..]` and get the list `[False, True]`. (Unfortunately, due to current parsing ambiguities, you can't write `[False..]` because it then assumes `False` is a module.)

Answer (score 8):

Try using a lambda.

```
> :t \x y -> [x..y]
```

The notation is just syntactic sugar for `enumFrom` and `enumFromTo` so it doesn't really have a conventional type.